# efficient way to count frequency of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D matrix, for example:

```
r_nm = np.array([[1, 3 ,4, 4,4],
                 [3 ,2, 2, 1,2],
                 [4 ,2, 1 ,1,3],
                 [4, 1 ,1, 2,1],
                 [4, 2 ,3, 1,1]])
```

I want to get the frequency of each element in this 2D array. np.unique and bincount doesn't work for 2D array.

How can I get the result like:

```
[(1,9)]   #1 appears 9 times
[(2,6)]
[(3,4)]
[(4,6)]
```

Or `{1:9,2:6,3:4,4:6}` in dict form?

Btw, how about when it comes to count frequency in a 3D numpy array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `np.unique(r_nm, return_counts=True)`? For dict form : `dict(zip(*..))`.

Comment: You need to show us what you tried (for this and future questions). `Doesn't work` doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Thank you Divakar! Yes, it returns a turple I need. I should check the manual more serious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [scipy.stats.itemfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html)

```
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
itemfreq(r_nm)
```

[image: Screenshot of the ouput]

np.unique works too

```
import numpy as np
(unique, counts) = np.unique(r_nm, return_counts=True)
frequencies = np.asarray((unique, counts)).T
```

[Screenshot of Output with np.unique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPdhy.png)